# Tableau different color formatting for many measures on same sheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have 4 measures being tabulated for one dimension.

For each measure can I color code based on an average value for that particular measure?

Like, in this example:
Say I want to color code cycletime based on an average value 600 & SLOC by average value 3000.

[image]

I have uploaded a pic of the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you want single chart for all this above information.

Step1:
I have graph like this:
[image]

Step2:
Take your measure values into rows and remove all other variables: Row should have Measure value and column should have id
[image]

Step3:
In filter measure name will be there then click on edit filters and select only those variables which you want to include in graph.

Step4:
put measure value in color as given in this link and you will get desired results
[image]

Hope this will work.